# How to resolve AnguarJS $injector:modulerr (details inside)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, dependency-injection

I've been having trouble using custom directives for my web app. When I pull up the JS console in Chrome, I get this `Failed to instantiate module w2l-direc due to:
{1}`. It seems that there's something wrong with the code I wrote in my module. I'm relatively new to angular so any feed back in regards to the following code would be appreciated

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('w2l-directives', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute']);
app.directive('gamesCol',['$http', function($http){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'games-col.html',
            controller: function(){
                this.games = $http.get('/js/games.json').success(function(data) {
                    this.games = data;
                });

                this.isSet = function(checkGame){
                    return this.game === checkGame;
                };

                this.setGame = function(activeGame){
                    this.game = activeGame;
                };
            },
            controllerAs:'game'
        };
    }]);

    app.directive('testimonyCol', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'testimonies-col.html',
            controller: function(){
                this.testimonials = $http.get('/js/testimonies.json').successs(function(data) {
                    this.testimonials = data;
                }); 
                this.current = 0
                this.currentTestimony = testimonies[current];

                this.setTestimony = function(checked){
                    if (checked !== this.currentTestimony) {
                    this.current = checked || 0;
                    }
                };
            },
            controllerAs:'testimony'
        };
    });
})();`
```

Comment: I see a typo in your code. It should be 'ui.bootstrap' not 'ui.bootstap'. May be that is causing the error.

Comment: Thanks, that would eliminate a possible issue. But I can't even get my own module to work, I'll have to check to see if I have ui.route's script file

Comment: try removing all dependencies and then add them one by one. May be this may help to figure out the exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message looks weird to me, it should have included a reason in stead of {1}.

Anyway, what comes to mind, is that angular can't find your module dependencies.
Can you check that ui.route's script file is included on the page?

ui.bootstrap is not part of the angular distro. You can find it here: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/. (Or simply remove the dependency, if you are not using it)

Comment: what would be the name of said script file?

Comment: Added to the response

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint: try to check your code in Firefox console, it gives you more detail information about your problem than chrome.

Comment: Checked on firebug and Web console on firefox. The error message I get is illegible. I'll add it to the OP shortly.