# Using Jest for unit test in angular 1.6

Tags: angularjs, jestjs

I'm trying to test my angular service that uses the Marvel API, and I was following [this article](https://curtistimson.co.uk/post/angularjs/angularjs-jest-unit-testing/), but I can't figure it out what I'm doing wrong.

**Error**

```
Failed to instantiate module marvel due to:{1}
```

**My app.js**

```
(() => {
  angular.module('marvel', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngAria',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngMaterial'
  ])
})()
```

**My Test Spec code**

```
require('../../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js')
require('../../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js');
require('../../src/app/app.js')
require('../../src/app/services/marvel.service.js')

describe('\nFail Cases', () => {
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('marvel'))
  let _marvelservice
  beforeEach(inject((MarvelService) => {
    _marvelservice = MarvelService
  }));

  test('should return false when user do not put the id for details correctly', (done) => {
    _marvelservice.getDetail()
      .catch((err) => {
        expect(err.xhrStatus).toBe('error')
      })
  })
})
```

**Marvel Service**

```
(() => {
  angular.module('marvel')
    .factory('MarvelService', ($http, $q, Config) => {
      /**
       * Get 10 characters from Marvel API.
       * @return {Object} Doc with all character recovered.
       */
      function getCharacters () {
        return request('', 'GET', { ts: 1, limit: 10, apikey: 
       `${Config.MARVEL.PUBLIC_KEY}`, hash: `${Config.MARVEL.MD5}` })
      }

      /**
       * Get details from a characters by consulting the Marvel API.
       * @return {Object} Doc with detail character recovered.
       */
      function getDetail (id) {
        const urlAddress = `/${id}`
        return request(urlAddress, 'GET', { ts: 1, apikey: 
        `${Config.MARVEL.PUBLIC_KEY}`, hash: `${Config.MARVEL.MD5}` })
      }

      /**
       * Responsible for request.
       * @return {Object} Doc with the returned promise.
       */
      function request (path, method, querystring) {
         const options = {
          method,
          url: `${Config.MARVEL.URL}${path}`,
          params: querystring
      }

      return $http(options)
        .then(success => { return success.data }, (err) => {
          return err
        })
      }

      return {
        getCharacters,
        getDetail
      }
    })
})()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is exactly as the error says. There should be `marvel` module, and it's not there.

`angular.module('marvel')` is module getter. It's expected that the module has been already defined with `angular.module('marvel', [])`.

Comment: Good! I correct the code following your answer, and it correct the problem, but now I have a problema with the marvel.service,have you faced this problem ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25582595/3731501 . You don't have these modules loaded. I think you would hit same problems with Jasmine as well. The problem is that you will have all these modules (ui.router, etc) be loaded in service unit test. The proper approach is to have sub-modules that won't have all these dependencies.